# can't filter an empty array inside another array (typescript)

Tags: arrays, typescript

It's my first time here so don't be mad if I forget to mention something :)

I'm working on a Typescript task and would need some help.
I have this value:
`let values = [["id-1", "id_2"], true, true]` (length is 3).

The first array with the id's is a multiselect dropdown, so when I unselect them, I have this `values =  [[], true, true]` (length is still 3).

I would like to filter this array to have a length of 2 (in this case), and push out of the array the empty array.

the type of the array is "boolean | string[]", I tried to check the length, I tried indexOf...but it doesn't work.
Any idea?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your intention to filter all "empty" values for the array including `false` `boolean` values?  Or just to remove empty arrays?

This logic removes empty arrays only.  The `.filter()` callback returns `true` when an item should be kept.  So we say that if `value` is an `array`, return `true` only if the length is greater than `0`.  But if it's not an `array` then just always return `true`.

```
type MyArrayType = (boolean | string[])[];

const filterMyArray = (array: MyArrayType): MyArrayType => {
    return array.filter(value => Array.isArray(value) ? value.length > 0 : true )
}

const a =  [["id-1", "id_2"], true, true]
const b = [[], true, true]
const c = [[], false, true]

console.log(filterMyArray(a)); // -> [["id-1", "id_2"], true, true] 
console.log(filterMyArray(b)); // -> [true, true] 
console.log(filterMyArray(c)); // -> [false, true]
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCCAnRBDEAVc0C8UAUARgPZEA2EKAdlAD5QDOwiAlpQOYDaAugJTcDcAWABQIgMZFKjKADNmpYBERwkqEFFx4UyNAC5YCHRiw99Ko5kgaAfFADeIqE6iIIwAK6Jq2tQDo5Ckp4AG4opO44tqpovsz00SAhYRE8UAD8UKHhEL7k7MAAFlC2AAxQ%20kwRUDwiAL4i4pLSKBpOHBwARMwAJgC0AIwdADRQXd0A%20gBMHVwjlRBziBFcjVLAUASt7bNQ84vLq9JiW9wjMmH0C7tLECuiwhJSZDmkRGx4AYrKhmpaPDz8KAAeiBUF6tnaYwGw1GPSmM32V3mXCgh2euTeH3kX3MvwI-0BILBEL212WqIeTXRr3enyUuLQeDEBOBoPBUA451Il0RKKAA)